# How do I redirect a request from an Apache Server to a local thin-Webserver?

Tags: apache-2.4, web-server, proxy, reverse-proxy, thin

I am experimenting with [dashing-icinga](https://github.com/dnsmichi/dashing-icinga2) at the moment and got everything up and running locally right now, but I cannot open the dashboard from another computer on the network via a reverse proxy on my apache-webserver yet.
I am kind of new to this topic and would need some help in getting my `httpd.conf` right, this is how the relevant part looks right now:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName dummy-server-name.needhelp.de
Redirect / https://dummy-server-name.needhelp.de/

ProxyPass /dashing-icinga https://dummy-server-name.needhelp.de:8005/dashing-icinga
ProxyPassReverse /dashing-icinga https://dummy-server-name.needhelp.de:8005/dashing-icinga
```

The thin-server is listening on `Port 8005`, but after restarting my `httpd.service` and opening `dummy-server-name.needhelp.de/dashing-icinga`, I get redirected to my "No page found" default-page.

Any help appreciated, please let me know if you need additional information or different parts of my config-files.

**EDIT 1**

When trying to connect to `dummy-server-name.needhelp.de/dashing-icinga`, the apache-server logs the following to `error_log`:

```
[proxy:error] [pid 172145] (13)Permission denied: AH00957: HTTPS: attempt to connect to 127.0.0.1:8005 (localhost) failed
```

Comment: Do you have proxypass on `virtualhost *:443`?

Comment: No, currently I have set up a VirtualHost with ProxyPass-Entries for *:80 only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

repair

`ProxyPass /dashing-icinga https://dummy-server-name.needhelp.de:8005/dashing-icinga`

to

`ProxyPass /dashing-icinga http://dummy-server-name.needhelp.de:8005/dashing-icinga`

or if inciga listen only on localhost

`ProxyPass /dashing-icinga http://127.0.0.1:8005/dashing-icinga`

Comment: Exactly, if the destionation really was HTTPS an additional directive would have been needed to enable this `SSLProxyEngine on`